# How to remove element from array or move to new array in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, yii2-advanced-app

I have an array `$item` in my Yii2 project, and I'm using dual listbox for elimination useless headers, I got headers from an imported Excel file.

The dual listbox has 2 box, left-box (Unselected) and right-box(Selected).
At the firsttime, all headers from `$item` showed in left-box, and then user drag/move the headers that want to use from left-box to right-box. When the headers moved to right-box, each headers has `data-sortindex` as an `id`.
So the the unselected headers in left-box doesn't has a `data-sortindex` as `id`.

Can anybody tell how to remove all the unselected headers from the array?

#### Array

```
Array
{
   [0] => Array
          {
             [0] => nim
             [1] => class
             [2] => age
             [3] => gender
             [4] => address
             [5] => skill
           }   
}
```

#### Dua listbox

[image]

From the picture above, you can see that I want to remove the `class` and `gender` from `$item` array when the button clicked.

I have another idea like set the selected headers to a new array. But I need the array's name still `$item`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: As soon as you see the listboxes in your browser, the variable will not exist anymore as the php script has finished. You need to store your data in for example a database and use ajax to update it whenever something changes.

Comment: Right and left box is it a text area ?

Comment: Ok I'll try your suggest, thanks @jeroen :)

Comment: May be, but I'm not sure what it is, this is the code in the view 
`<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'list_header')->widget(DualListbox::className(), [
                'items' => $items,
                'options' => $options,
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'selectedListLabel' => 'Header Akhir',
                    'nonSelectedListLabel' => 'Header Awal',
                    'moveOnSelect' => false,
                    'showFilterInputs' => false,
                ],
            ])
            ->label('');
    ?>`